# How to put google font (chevron_right) at front of a link in html?

Tags: html, css

I am using google fonts in html and I want to put a google font (chevron_icon) at the front of a link but the problem is that it is placing it under the link instead of front. Here is my code.

```
<div class="mobile-navigation">
            <ul id = "mobile-nav" class="side-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" onclick = "openList()"> Fashion </a> <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
                    <ul id = "submenu1">
                        <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Underwear</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Electronics</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

The output that it shows is something like this.

File

>

Electronics

I want the following output.

File>

Electronics

Comment: Surely the chevron is at the end and not the front?  but it looks as if you have made your link a block element - please can you show some css for the nav

Answer (score 1):

You are placing the chevron in the wrong place, you need to put it like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick = "openList()"> Fashion <i class="material-icons">&#62; (chevron_right)</i></a>
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vtkLy29r/1/

Comment: It starts overriding the **Electronics** list element.

Comment: What do you mean? @AbdulMalik That does not seem possible and or correct as the HTML output for the **Electronics** list element is completely different.

Comment: You need to provide a visual aid because I can't understand why it would happen. Please provide some more code or edit the fiddle link I provided to show the issue.

Comment: The same code is working perfectly fine over there at fiddle link.

Comment: If the code is working in the fiddle, please accept my answer as it is correct and I cannot understand your problem. I have answered the question for you already. I cannot help further if you don't provide your code, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<a href="#" onclick = "openList()"> Fashion <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a>
```

Comment: It starts overriding the **Electronics** list element.

Comment: Can you please post your code so that we can see why it would be do this